# Did Relativity's Terran 1 booster survive the fall to the ocean for recovery?

Tags: booster

There is no plan to recover the booster of the Terran 1 rocket launched yesterday. Did the booster survive (not necessarily intact) the fall to the ocean and the impact with the surface of the water? Could it be recovered by a third party?

Comment: If recovery by a third party was on the cards, there are a few Falcon 9 boosters which were "soft landed" in the ocean (ie they tested landing systems and hovered the booster above the water before letting it splash down) and never recovered... Probably the best unrecovered hardware there is out there on an ocean floor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How not-intact is okay for you?  [Portions of Saturn V first-stage engines have been recovered from the seafloor](https://www.space.com/37830-jeff-bezos-apollo-rocket-engines-recovery.html) after ocean impact, so there's precedent if you only want the pieces to be somewhat recognizable.